A differential equation and recurrence related to P-partitions
I am interested in polynomials $G_n(z)$ defined by the recurrence
$$G_{n+1}(z) - 2G_n(z) + (1-nz)G_{n-1}(z)=0$$
for $n\ge1$ with the initial values $G_0(z) = 1$ and $G_1(z) = 1$.
The next few values are $G_2(z) = 1+z$, $G_3(z) = 1+4z$, $G_4(z) = 1+10z + 3z^2$. I'd like to find a formula or generating function for these polynomials, which are related to certain P-partitions.
Let $g(x,z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty G_{n+1}(z)\, x^n/n!$. Then $g=g(x,z)$ satisfies the differential equation
$g'' -2g'+g =xzg'+2zg$, with initial conditions $g(0)=1$, where the prime is the derivative with respect to $x$. From this it is not hard to show that
$g(x,1) =e^{x^2/2+2x}$.
Maple claims to solve this differential equation in terms of the Kummer $M$ and $U$ functions. (The Kummer $M$ function is just the confluent hypergeometric function $_1F_1$ and the Kummer $U$ function is related.) However the formula that Maple gives involves terms like $M(-1/(2z), 1/2, 2/z)$ that that are singular at $z=0$. Is there a formula for $g(x,z)$ that can be used to compute its coefficients?
(I would also be interested in a combinatorial interpretation to the polynomials $G_n(z)$; it's not hard to show that its coefficients are nonnegative.)
If we define $h(x,z) = e^{-x}g(x,z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty H_{n}(z)\, x^n/n!$ then $h(x,z)$ satisfies the differential equation
$h''=(2+x)z h+zxh'$ and $H_n(z)$ satisfies the recurrence $H_{n+2}(z) = z(nH_{n-1}(z) + (n+2) H_n(z))$, with initial values $H_0(z)=1$, $H_1(z)=z$. The polynomials $H_n(z)$ have fewer nonzero coefficients and smaller coefficients than $G_n(z)$, which suggests that they may be simpler: $H_2(z) = 2z$, $H_3(z)=z+3z^2$, $H_4(z) = 10z^2$.

Singularity of solutions is common issue for differential equations in Maple. I've seen many examples of differential equations that Maple can solve only if the boundary condition is dropped, and the produced general solutions become singular when the condition is fixed. A recent example of that kind: https://mathoverflow.net/q/467385

Maple does produce a solution with the boundary conditions, but it is singular at 0.
